# JS Question: How do I make my level 0 flow to level 1 in my chat prompt

Tags: javascript, if-statement, flowchart

I'm working on a message chat flow diagram where you input answers and it'll give you a reply working through the chart. However, I can't get my first level to connect with my second level. I can type in "name" and it will return correctly, but when I type in yes to answer then Do you like ice cream question. I get an undefined reply.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
let level = 0;
let path;

const getReply = (userInput) => {
if (level === 0) {
level = 1;
if (userInput === "name") {
path = "name";
return "Hello, name. Do you have like ice cream?";
}
}


if (level === 1) {
level = 2;
if (path === "yes") {
if (userInput === "yes") {
  return "Great, what flavour do you like?";
 }
 }
```

Comment: You assign `path = "name"`. You check `if (path === "yes") {` Note: ignore if this is intended behaviour, i just thought this to be a little weird.

Comment: I commented out that path = name line, but when I answer "yes" to the do you like ice cream it just comes back undefined. Why is it not connecting?

Comment: Coz `path === "yes"` is always false

Answer (score 0):

```js
let level = 0;

const getReply = (userInput) => {
  if (level === 0) {
    level = 1;
    return "Hello, name. Do you have like ice cream?";
  }

  if (level === 1) {
    level = 2;
    if (userInput === "yes") {
      return "Great, what flavour do you like?";
    }
  }
}

console.log(getReply('Jack'));
console.log(getReply('yes'));

level = 0;
console.log(getReply('Jill'));
console.log(getReply('no'));
```